# I want to select xpath of the following dropdown list of Airports

Tags: selenium, xpath

Here if I type in something then the list of airports matching that text are shown up!! So is there a general way by which I can select the xpath for it? Here is the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sitLr.png)

and here is the HTML:

```
<document>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<body>
<!-- Keeping body block so that it can be used by public site as well. -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div id="timezone-change-dialog" class="col-md-12 content content-confirmation hidden">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 wizard-steps-container">
<div class="col-md-12 content">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<form id="id_create-shipment-step-2" class="form-horizontal has-validation-callback fv-form fv-form-bootstrap" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="novalidate">
<button class="fv-hidden-submit" type="submit" style="display: none; width: 0px; height: 0px;"/>
<input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="gk0wq70Am8U0sKat5IJ6f8nKquxYlZaz" autocomplete="off" type="hidden"/>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<div id="pickup_airport" class="form-group" style="display: block;">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="">
<div class="col-sm-6 has-success">
<div class="typeahead-container result hint">
<div class="typeahead-field">
<div class="typeahead-result">
<ul class="typeahead-list">
<li class="typeahead-item">
<a href="javascript:;" data-group="airports" data-index="0">
<span>
(
<strong>AIR</strong>
) Aripuana
<strong>Air</strong>
port, Aripuana, MT, BR
</span>
</a>
</li>
<li class="typeahead-item">
<li class="typeahead-item active">
```

Comment: The xpath is `//li/a[@data-group='airports']` this will select all list item.

Comment: and if I have to select the first airport, then what could I do ? @Murthi  https://www.dropbox.com/s/bk4rj35k9c63zxz/Screenshot%202017-06-05%2023.45.20.png?dl=0

Comment: @Sammy, use `//li/a[@data-group='airports' and @data-index='0']` to match only first node

Comment: To select first item, use the following, `//li[1]/a[@data-group='airport s']`

Answer (score 0):

If the span contains text and it is under li tag then you can do that like this.

//span[contains(text(),'airports')]/parent::li